# Is Microsoft able to know programs you have installed in your machine

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

Is *Microsoft* able to know which programs do you have installed, in order to request you about licences you may or may not have?

Currently i have *Windows 8* installed on my machine, and i am worried about Microsoft knowing about other programs, such as *Microsoft Office*, *Microsoft Access*, among others.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

At the [Microsoft Privacy](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement) site, we can read the following extracted paragraph:

> **Personal Data We Collect**
>
> ***Device and Usage data.*** We collect data about your device and how you
>   and your device interact with Microsoft and our products. For example,
>   we collect:
>
> *Device, connectivity and configuration data.* We collect data about
>   your device and the network you use to connect to our products. It
>   includes data about the operating systems and other software installed
>   on your device, including product keys. It also includes IP address,
>   device identifiers (such as the IMEI number for phones), regional and
>   language settings.

Comment: Probably, if you have all the telemetry enabled.

Comment: Desktop applications, no, Windows Store (UWP) by their very nature you link an UWP to your Microsoft Account in most cases.  Edit your question to be specific about what type of application your worried about MS is tracking (all programs are too broad of a subject)

Comment: I am concerned if Microsoft can track information of Microsoft products (OS, Office) from a Windows 8 machine

Comment: @hyprfrco If I were in Microsoft's position, I would ensure that every application "called home" to verify the license *regardless of your telemetry settings*. Office 365 is cheap, and Google Docs is free. Best way not to get caught is to stay legal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you worried